# MEKA >> Error: Could not find or load main class .\lib\Jama.jar

Tags: java, weka

I have Windows7 OS and want to use **MEKA GUI** what I did is the following:

1. downloading meka-release1.5.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/meka/files/meka-1.5.0/
2. extracting it, and type run.bat in cmd.exe

But I had the following Error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class .\lib\Jama.jar

Can any one help with clear steps how to install and use MEKA EXplorer?

Comment: In the current dir do you have  .\lib\Jama.jar ?

Comment: Yup , I have jama.jar it is in lib folder

Comment: you should have lib/Jama.jar, not Jama.jar

Comment: i have lib folder inside it all jars including jama.jar

Comment: anyway very probably you are having spaces in the path. unzip all in c:\tmp and retry

Comment: by the way, are you using a jvm >= 6?

Comment: thanks , but it doesn't work !
Iam using jvm 7

Comment: so, suppose you have c:\tmp\meka\run.bat, you should do: 'cd c:\tmp\meka\'  then 'run.bat'

Comment: yes, I exactly did that

Comment: but same error appears again !

Comment: are you having more run.bat files in the env path variable? Try forcing the meka's version, by calling ".\run.bat"

Comment: true I have run.sh

I have try it (.\run.bat) in vain :(

I add the path (c:\tmp\meka\lib) to "System variables" path in "Environment variable" but in vain

Comment: run.sh is for unix version... I'm going to write an answer, it should work also for you (in my system works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have unzipped it into `c:\tmp\meka\`, so you have `c:\tmp\meka\run.bat`, you can:

1. open a shell (`cmd.exe`)
2. go inside your tmp dir: `cd c:\tmp\meka\`'
3. call `.\run.bat`'

You should at least use a JRE >= 6, because the script is using the *star* notation in order to list the Jars:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET MEMORY=512m
SET MAIN=meka.gui.explorer.Explorer

java -Xmx%MEMORY% -cp ".\lib\*" %MAIN% %1
```

Comment: I try this on pc it works 100% ..
but on my laptop the same error I have is above!

Comment: but I need it in my laptop !!

Comment: does your laptop run a Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem, only way to fix was adding all jar files to the -cp option

```
java -Xmx%MEMORY% -cp  "lib\Jama.jar;lib\junit.jar;lib\meka-1.5.jar;lib\moa.jar;lib\mst.jar;lib\mulan.jar;lib\weka.jar;lib\weka-test.jar" %MAIN% %1
```